# Axiom of regularity - basic question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\{\emptyset, S\}$, then the axiom of regularity holds, since $S \cap 
\emptyset=\emptyset$. However, $S \in S$, which makes me conclude that the axiom of regularity does not prevent sets containing sets, just infinite descending chains of set memberships. Is that so?

Answer (score 2):

If $S=\{\varnothing,S\}$ then the set $\{S\}$ has no $\epsilon$-minimal element which is "forbidden" by the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

So if it occurs that $S=\{\varnothing,S\}$ then apparantly the axiom of regularity does *not* hold.

---

The axiom does prevent any set $x$ to contain $x$ as element: if $x\in x$ then there is no $y\in\{x\}$ such that $y\cap\{x\}=\varnothing$.

This because $y=x$ is the only choice but we have $x\in x\cap\{x\}$.

Comment: You mean that regularity holds for $S$, but not for $\{S\}$, since $\{S\} \cap S = \{S\} \cap \{\emptyset, S\} = \{S\}$ ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the phrase "regularity holds for $S$"? That $S$ contains a set $x$ that satisfies $x\cap S=\varnothing$ maybe?

Comment: Exactly. The element $\emptyset$ makes regularity hold for S, given that $S \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ .

Comment: @TylerD007 Regularity does not hold for a single set, but is a property of (all sets in) the theory. Similar to how "Extensionality" or "Comprehension" does not hold for a specific set. The proper way to call $S$ is to say $S$ is / isn't *well-founded by $\in$*.

Comment: Then (in accordance with comment of @Vsotvep) you better say that $S$ has an $\epsilon$-minimal element. The axiom of regularity states the every set has an $\epsilon$-minimal element.   Further a set can be "regular" but that has a special definition (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665403/75923) for that). Another way to state the axiom of regularity is saying that "every set is regular".