# Is the set that contains a set which contains the original set a set in Zermelo-Frankel set theory?

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

So a buddy asked me if the box which contained everything contained itself. So, from the tidbits I know, I tell them that according to ZFC, no. However, after that my mind spawned a new question:
Is $S=\{\{S\}\}$ a set? I was originally post this question without attempt, but after a few $n$-ty minutes ($n\in\mathbb{N}$), I have came up with a disproof. So, can anyone point out any flaws?
(Note: Standard ZFC axioms with set equality, set intersection and the empty set defined.)

**Statement**: $\nexists x[x=\{\{x\}\}]$
**Proof**:
Assume $S=\{\{S\}\}$.
Then since $\{S\}\in S$, $\{S\}$ is a set.
Therefore, by the axiom of pairing, $U:= \{S, \{S\}\}$ is also a set.
However, as we will now show, this set does not satisfy the axiom of regularity.
Consider $U\cap x$ where $x\in U$.
Since $U$ is a finite set, we may check by case that $U\cap x=\varnothing$.
Case 1: $x=S$.
$U\cap x=\{S, \{S\}\}\cap\{\{S\}\}=\{S\}\implies x\neq S$
Case 2: $x={S}$
$U\cap x=\{S, \{S\}\}\cap\{S\}=S\implies x\neq \{S\}$
Since neither cases hold, our assumption must be false.
Thus we have proven our statement.
$\blacksquare \; \mathrm{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: If you have [Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#For_every_two_sets,_only_one_can_be_an_element_of_the_other) it is enough after step 2 above to note that $S \in \{ S \}$ that, in conjunction with $\{ S \} \in S$, contradicts the axiom.

Comment: I don’t understand your case 1. You write $U \cap x = \{S, \{S\}\} \cap \{\{S\}\}$. But I don’t see why this equality should hold, since $x= S$. It should be $U \cap x = \{S, \{S\}\} \cap S$. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: $ U∩x=\{S,\{S\}\}∩S$ is agreed upon. Then, by the substitution property of equality, $ U∩x=\{S,\{S\}\}∩S=\{S,\{S\}\}∩\{\{S\}\}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA how?

Comment: "Is $S=\{\{S\}\}$ a set?..." I would rather reformulate this as "is there a set $S$ that satisfies $S=\{\{S\}\}$?". There are indeed no [regular sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665403/75923) that satisfy this.

Comment: See linked text: "For every two sets, only one can be an element of the other. Let X and Y be sets. Then apply the axiom of regularity to the set {X,Y} (which exists by the axiom of pairing). We see there must be an element of {X,Y} which is also disjoint from it. It must be either X or Y. By the definition of disjoint then, we must have either Y is not an element of X or vice versa."

Comment: Hey, that sounds an awful lot like my proof

Comment: Where are you getting the equality $\{S, \{S\}\} \cap S = \{S, \{S\}\} \cap \{\{S\}\}$? You say it’s using the substitution property of equality. What substitution did you use to get this?

Comment: @MarkSaving It is stated in the assumption that $S=\{\{S\}\}$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Then your proof is correct.

Comment: @E030E03: I just wanted to point out that in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, there is no such thing as "the set which contains everything". In other words, the formula $\{x:x=x\}$ does not define a set – rather, it defines a *proper class*. Perhaps you already knew this, but it wasn't completely clear to me from your question.

Comment: @Joe, how does that relate to the question?

Comment: @E030E03: It doesn't. I just wanted to clarify something in case you weren't clear on how $\mathsf{ZFC}$ avoids Russell's paradox.